# Xalan and the document() function

Tags: java, xslt, xpath, xalan

Since I have spent almost a full day now on debugging this, I hope to get some valuable insight on SO on following problem:

I am running an XSL Transformation on an input document, my stylesheet loads an external XML-Document which contains lookup values I need to do some comparisons.
I am loading the external document like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="dictionary"
    select="document('myDict.xml', document(''))/path/to/LookupElement" />
```

`LookupElement` is an element which contains the complete XML-Fragment I need to access.
Throughout the stylesheet various comparison expressions are accessing `$dictionary`.
Now, what happens is, that the transformation with this `document()` function call in place takes about 12 (!) minutes using Xalan (2.7.?, latest version, downloaded from the Apache website, not the one contained in the JRE).

The same stylesheet without the `document()` call (and without my comparisons accessing data in `$dictionary`) completes in seconds.

The same stylesheet using Saxon-B 9.1.0.8 completes in seconds as well.

Information: The external document has 25MB(!) and there is no possibility for me to reduce its size.
I am running the transformations using the xslt-Task of ant under JRE 6.

I am not sure if this has anything to do with above mentioned problem: Throughout my stylesheet I have expressions that test for existence of certain attributes in the external XML-Document. These expressions *always* evaluate to `true`, regardless of whether the attributes exist or not:

```
<xsl:variable name="myAttExists" select="boolean($dictionary/path/to/@myAttribute)"/>
```

I am at the end of my wits. I know that Xalan correctly reads the document, all references go to `$dictionary`, so I am not calling `document()` multiple times.

Anybody *any* idea?

**Edit:**

I have removed the reference to the XML-Schema from the external XML-Document to prevent Schema-Lookups of Xalan or the underlying (Xerces) Parser.

**Edit:**

I have verified that `myAttExists` will *always* be `true`, even if specifiying an attribute name that for sure does not exist in the entire external XML-Document.
I have even changed the above expression to:

```
<xsl:variable name="myAttExists" select="count($dictionary/path/to/@unknownAttribute) != 0"/>
```

which still yields `true`.

**Edit**:

I have removed the call to the `document()` function and all references to `$dictionary` for testing purposes. This reduces transformation runtime with Xalan to 16 seconds.

**Edit:**

Interesting detail: The Xalan version shipped with Oxygen 12.1 completes within seconds loading the external XML-Document. However, it also evaluates the existence of attributes incorrectly...

**Edit:**

I have the following variable declaration which *always* yields `true`:

```
<xsl:variable name="expectedDefaultValueExists">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@index">
            <xsl:value-of select="boolean($dictionary/epl:Object[@index = $index]/@defaultValue)"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="boolean($dictionary/epl:Object[@index = $index]/epl:SubObject[@subIndex = $subIndex]/@defaultValue)"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

Is this possible in XSLT/XPath 1.0? `$index` and `$subIndex` are calculated from the `@index` and `@subIndex` attributes of the context node. I want to load the `defaultValue` attribute from the external XML-Document which has an equal index and/or subIndex.
Is it possible to use variables in predicates in XPath 1.0? This works in XPath 2.0.
Regarding the incorrect variable assignment, I don't believe in a parser (Xalan) issue anymore, since PHPs XSLTProcessor does the same. It must be an issue in the variable declaration...

Comment: Well if you know that Saxon works fine and with good performance then why do you bother with Xalan and XSLT 1.0, as you use a Xalan version not in the JRE you use a third party library anyway and could directly move to Saxon 9. Of course the term LookupElement suggests that defining and using a key might improve performance, you would need to show us more details of the structure of the XML and `myDict.xml` and the use of it in the XSLT.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I need to maintain an XSLT 1.0 and 2.0 version of my stylesheets because they are used in different environments. Otherwise I would have abandoned the 1.0 version already.
I am pointing the variable directly to the Element that contains all the data I need. Since this is a direct XPath, I don't see how there could be any performance issues?

Comment: My first guess would be that it is loading DTDs (such as the XHTML DTD) from the W3C web site. W3C artificially throttles such requests in order to discourage them. However, since the Saxon you are using is a rather old release (9.1) the same problem would affect Saxon as well, so perhaps that's not it.

Comment: @MichaelKay In fact I found information on that issue before. There is no DTD referenced in the external XML-Document, and I removed the reference to its XML-Schema for that very reason as well. To no avail :(

Comment: Hard to answer without seeing your input and stylesheet. Question: How long does it take to run if you restructure your input such that the thing you're reading via document() is the primary XML input?

Comment: Also: I presume you've asked this question on Apache's own Xalan mailing list? That's the best place to find expertise on the Apache code these days. (I've been away from XSLT for two years, and away from Apache Xalan for several times that.)

Comment: @keshlam The problem is, the stylesheet is generated (Schematron) with a few 10k LOC, very difficult to debug anything there for somebody not into Schematron and the specific domain. What exactly do you mean by primary XML input? To run the stylesheet on the external XML document? Concerning Xalans mailing list: not yet, I guess this will be my next stop if I have the time to look into this further..

Comment: Without seeing what's happening, we can't debug it. And this is a problem of a size which really is more in the Xalan support list's domain than ours, unless you can do the work to isolate it by trimming that stylesheet and the input docs down to size.

Comment: "I have the following variable declaration which always yields true" - this depends what you mean by "yields true".  In XSLT 1.0 a variable with element content rather than a select will always be a result tree fragment, and `value-of` generates text nodes.  The value of the variable will be a tree fragment with one child text node whose value will be the string representation of boolean true or false, and both of these possible tree fragments are "truthy" values when they are subsequently treated as boolean.

Comment: @IanRoberts I mean that using $expectedDefaultValueExists in any `<xsl:if>` or `<xsl:when>` test expression executes the branch. I am not quite sure if I understand you correctly. How would you assign that variable in order to set it `true` if `@defaultValue` exists and `false` otherwise?

Comment: @IanRoberts You actually answered my second question. Want to write an answer? I just looked up the XSLT 1.0 spec, the value of the variable is indeed a result tree fragment, which contains a root node with one child (text-) node in my case, as you correctly stated. Any test on this variable, will return `true` because the implicitely called `boolean` function returns `true` if the node-set is non-empty. I am just curious why this works in XSLT 2.0. There I have `as="xs:boolean"`, which should convert acc. to the function conversion rules. Those however, don't mention string to boolean conv.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This only answers the last part of the question, but it's getting too unwieldy for comments...*

> I have the following variable declaration which always yields true when used as the `test` of an `xsl:if` or `xsl:when`:

```
<xsl:variable name="expectedDefaultValueExists">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@index">
            <xsl:value-of select="boolean($dictionary/epl:Object[@index = $index]/@defaultValue)"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="boolean($dictionary/epl:Object[@index = $index]/epl:SubObject[@subIndex = $subIndex]/@defaultValue)"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

In XSLT 1.0 a variable with a body rather than a `select` always becomes a "result tree fragment", in this case with a single text node child that will contain the string "true" or "false" as appropriate.  Any non-empty RTF is considered *true* when converted to boolean.

In XSLT 2.0 it's a similar story - 2.0 doesn't distinguish between node sets and result tree fragments, but still the variable will be a "temporary tree" with a single text node child whose value is the string "true" or "false", and both these trees are *true* when converted to boolean.  If you want to get an actual boolean value out of the variable then you need to change two things - add `as="xs:boolean"` to the variable declaration and use `xsl:sequence` instead of `xsl:value-of`:

```
<xsl:variable name="expectedDefaultValueExists" as="xs:boolean">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@index">
            <xsl:sequence select="boolean($dictionary/epl:Object[@index = $index]/@defaultValue)"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:sequence select="boolean($dictionary/epl:Object[@index = $index]/epl:SubObject[@subIndex = $subIndex]/@defaultValue)"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

The `xsl:value-of` instruction converts the result of its `select` into a string and constructs a text node containing that string.  The `xsl:sequence` instruction simply returns the value from the `select` directly as whatever type it happens to be.

But there are simpler ways to achieve the same thing.  In XPath 2.0 you can do if/then/else constructs directly in the XPath

```
<xsl:variable name="expectedDefaultValueExists"
   select="if (@index)
           then $dictionary/epl:Object[@index = $index]/@defaultValue
           else $dictionary/epl:Object[@index = $index]/epl:SubObject[@subIndex = $subIndex]/@defaultValue" />
```

In 1.0 you need to be slightly more creative

```
<xsl:variable name="expectedDefaultValueExists"
   select="(@index and $dictionary/epl:Object[@index = $index]/@defaultValue)
        or (not(@index) and $dictionary/epl:Object[@index = $index]/epl:SubObject[@subIndex = $subIndex]/@defaultValue)" />
```

Comment: This is a great explanation. I also didn't know of the mentioned XPath 2.0 Syntax, the Xpath 1.0 solution is also way better than what I came up with. Thank you!